# VB.net richtextbox multiple colors to specified words

Tags: .net, vb.net, text-coloring

So my program reads a text file into a richtextbox. For example, I want all the words `"echo" "pause" "setlocal" to be blue`, `"%" to be orange` ", `"rem" "::" to be green` and so on. A lot of different words get different colors. Yes, the idea is so the richtextbox reads .bat files like notepad++ do color-wise.

I've figured out how to set a color to one word

```
Private Sub PreviewRTB_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PreviewRTB.TextChanged
    PreviewRTB.Multiline = True
    PreviewRTB.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical

    'Set Colors
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    Dim c_blue As String = "Echo"

    While index <> -1
        index = PreviewRTB.Find(c_blue, index, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord)
        If index <> -1 Then
            PreviewRTB.SelectionStart = index
            PreviewRTB.SelectionLength = c_blue.Length
            PreviewRTB.SelectionColor = Color.Blue
            index += c_blue.Length
        End If
    End While
```

But where do I set the rest of the words under dim c_blue? I tried `Dim c_blue As String = "Echo" & "setlocal" & "pause"` also tried to use `+` between as well, but it doesn't work. And how do I progress to add another color to other words? Thanks!

Comment: Unless you really want to do this part yourself, you are better of using something that's specifically built for this - like [ScintillaNET](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple coloring, provided that the text isn't too long, something like this will do:

```
Dim KeyWords As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)(New String() {"this", "word", "color"})
Dim KeyWordsColors As List(Of Color) = New List(Of Color)(New Color() {Color.Blue, Color.Red, Color.Green})
Private Sub PreviewRTB_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PreviewRTB.TextChanged
    Dim words As IEnumerable(Of String) = PreviewRTB.Text.Split(New Char() {" "c, ".", ",", "?", "!"})
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    Dim rtb As RichTextBox = sender 'to give normal color according to the base fore color
    For Each word As String In words
        'If the list contains the word, then color it specially. Else, color it normally
        'Edit: Trim() is added such that it may guarantee the empty space after word does not cause error
        coloringRTB(sender, index, word.Length, If(KeyWords.Contains(word.ToLower().Trim()), KeyWordsColors(KeyWords.IndexOf(word.ToLower().Trim())), rtb.ForeColor))
        index = index + word.Length + 1 '1 is for the whitespace, though Trimmed, original word.Length is still used to advance
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub coloringRTB(rtb As RichTextBox, index As Integer, length As Integer, color As Color)
    Dim selectionStartSave As Integer = rtb.SelectionStart 'to return this back to its original position
    rtb.SelectionStart = index
    rtb.SelectionLength = length
    rtb.SelectionColor = color
    rtb.SelectionLength = 0
    rtb.SelectionStart = selectionStartSave
    rtb.SelectionColor = rtb.ForeColor 'return back to the original color
End Sub
```

The idea here is pretty straight forward:

1. List the words you want to color
2. List the colors of those words
3. When the RTB text is changed, parse it with `String.Split` word by word (note that the condition "RTB text is changed" can be changed with anything you want)
4. Check the parsed word. If it is found, start coloring that word. If not, color it with default color
5. Go to the next word, till the text reading is finished.
6. Don't forget to increase the current index of the checker according to the `word.Length` `+1` for the whitespace

The result will be something like this:

[image]

Next (2)

[image]

Next (3)

[image]

Next (4)

[image]

Next (5)

[image]

> Note: If the text gets too long, consider of creating a timer (or some
>   other module) to periodically check your RTB instead of checking the
>   text when the text changed. Thus, when the text changed. You reset the
>   timer. When the text is not changed after sometimes, then you start to
>   implement the coloring logic for all the text. This way, you make the
>   word-color checker work significantly less.

Comment: Thanks for a great input. Giving this a try very soon.

Comment: @MadsTheMan yeah :) for simple text, this will do. It is definitely not good enough if you want to check something as complex as C# code though...

Comment: Fair enough, I think it'll do for my purpose. :) I'm testing it now. So far I can see that the output works when it has "!" "." "?" any of those you listed at the text.split part. However, " " (space) don't seem to work. So for example output `echo ` dont output color, but `echo !` gives echo color. Any ideas why that is? This is what I have at the split `PreviewRTB.Text.Split(New Char() {" ", " "c, ".", ",", "?", "!"})`

Comment: @MadsTheMan I think it is because the split would take that as `echo `. One workaround with this is by "trimming" the word string (`echo ` to `echo`) such that it can be checked by the `KeyWords`. But, beware that if you trim, then you also need to check the `length` difference before and after trimming.

Comment: Nice, that seems to be an possibility. I can see that this works, just needs a little tweaking for my purpose, but answer is accepted. Again thanks! Could you give me an example of what would be good as the word.lenght? I'm not quite sure if I understand fully what it does if I for example change from `+ 1` to `+ 3`. Or just a simple explanation.

Comment: Great! ;) glad that I can help. "Could you give me an example of what would be good as the word.length" -> sorry, I do not get it. Mind to elaborate? (especially: "...good as the word.Length"(?))

Comment: My bad. Its about the length difference. This part `...index = index + word.Length + 1` of the code. If i rise or lower the number, what will this output differently? I can see you wrote `'1 is for the whitespace`, but what does this actually mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101758/discussion-between-ian-and-madstheman).